# jQuery and mistake Unexpected token }

Tags: jquery

How does it display a properly without error:

```
onclick="jQeury( '.se342rf_asdd a[href=#stab2]' ).click(function() {jQeury('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 100%}, 0);}); return false;"
```

After a few displays an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

- `100%` to `'100%'`
- `jQeury` to `jQuery` (or `$`)

In addition, make the full code:

```
$( '.se342rf_asdd a[href=#stab2]' ).click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop : '100%'
    }, 0);
    return false;
}); // missing closing parentheses here
```

P.S. Put in `$(document).ready(function(){ /*Code here*/ });` for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `jQeury` to `jQuery` first

Also write it in document.ready()

```
jQuery( '.se342rf_asdd a[href=#stab2]' )
.click(function() {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop : '100%'}, 0); 
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled jquery

```
onclick="jQuery( '.se342rf_asdd a[href=#stab2]' ).click(function() {jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 100%}, 0);}); return false;"
```